# Why is the sum of results in SQL incompatible with the results of the original data?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
table1
id,link_kd, scost, syear

table2
id,link_kd, hcost, hyear
```

[this my fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4EXbNgeVraTK5jDnqx3XCU/0)

When I using join for sum and group by year the results incompatible
but if I do single query, the results is accurate

I want to sum scost and hcost by year. If have year but no data scost or hcost the results be zero.
But the main problem is my query incopatible with the results

Comment: What are your expected results?  A single sum per year or 1 for each cost column?

Comment: You are grouping by different columns in the two queries. What is wrong with your result?

Comment: @sgeddes i want to sum scost and hcost by year. if have a year but dont have data scost or hcost the results be zero. you can see on query 2. for scost 2017 have no data so i want 212 to be zero. and for hcost have wrong results.

Comment: @SalmanA yes i just reversing the query because im so confuse want to select base on table 1 or table 2. but still, both of them issued wrong results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to get a single sum per year, here's one option using `union all`:

```
SELECT year, SUM(scost) scostsum, 
FROM (
  SELECT syear as year, scost as cost from table1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT hyear as year, hcost as cost from table2 
  ) t
GROUP by year;
```

---

Based on your comment, if you want multiple sums, you have to create a years table and then use `outer joins` to get your scost and hcost.  Here's an example:

```
select year, coalesce(s.cost,0) as scost, coalesce(h.cost,0) as hcost
from (select syear as year from table1 union select hyear from table2) years
    left join (
      select syear, sum(scost) cost
      from table1 
      group by syear) s on years.year = s.syear
    left join (
      select hyear, sum(hcost) cost
      from table2 
      group by hyear) h on years.year = h.hyear
```